# iceWm windows manager windows issue

Tags: java, linux, jframe, debian, window-managers

I am running java application on Debian 9 which has **iceWm** window manager installed.

the java application has a main frame that has a single button on it and when clicking the button a new Jframe is drawn.

pressing on the button again will trigger the java functions **tofront** and **toback**

first time I start my application and i press on the button the second frame appears and pressing again it hides as expected, but after that if I press again
I will see that the frame tab is flashing but not showing in the window manager task bar!

I have tried to change the preferences for the IceWm window manager but it didn't help.

how can I make sure that every time the button is pressed and the **tofront** java function is called the new frame will show on the top of the main frame?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use twm it's easy to remove the title borders and you can
control all at java side. It's better for embedded application.

Follow my system.twmrc, you save it on /etc/X11

```
#
NoGrabServer
NoTitle
RandomPlacement
RestartPreviousState
DecorateTransients
#IconifyByUnmapping
#TitleFont "-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-*-*"
#ResizeFont "-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-*-*"
#MenuFont "-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-*-*"
#IconFont "-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*"
#IconManagerFont "-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-100-*-*-*"
ClientBorderWidth 2
BorderWidth 2
ButtonIndent 3
NoHighlight

# This is for hiding the ugly menubar in windows who dont need em.
NoTitle
{
 #   "x11amp"         # x11amp, the winamp lookalike, http://x11amp.ml.org.
 #   "xlogo"          # a must have :)
     "xosview"
}

Color
{
    BorderColor "gray85"
    DefaultBackground "black"
    DefaultForeground "gray85"
    TitleBackground "black"
    TitleForeground "gray85"
    MenuBackground "black"
    MenuForeground "gray85"
    MenuTitleBackground "gray65"
    MenuTitleForeground "black"
    IconBackground "black"
    IconForeground "white"
    IconBorderColor "black"
    IconManagerBackground "black"
    IconManagerForeground "gray85"
    PointerForeground "black"
    PointerBackground "white"

}

Cursors
{
                         Frame     "left_ptr"
                         Title     "left_ptr"
                         Icon      "left_ptr"
                         IconMgr   "left_ptr"
                         Move      "fleur"
                         Resize    "fleur"
                         Menu      "hand1"
                         Button    "hand2"
                         Wait      "clock"
                         Select    "dot"
                         Destroy   "pirate"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when I installed the twm, sikuli didn't run at all!! , moreover I am looking for a solution in which I wouldn't change the window manager.